# Server init failed RabbitMQ

Tags: erlang, rabbitmq

I'm trying to run rabbitmq (3.3.1) server on my computer (win 7 professional) and I'm using erlang 6.0 (OTP 17.0). Server refuses to start giving such output (console):

```
    {"init terminating in do_boot",
    {badarg,[{io,format,[<0.29.0>,"~n~nBOOT FAILED~n===========~n~n
    Error description:~n   ~p~n~n
    Log files (may contain more information):~n   ~s~n   ~s~n~n",
    [{could_not_start,rabbit,badarg},
    [67,58,47,85,115,101,114,115,47,80,105,111,116,114,32,82,97,99,104,119,97,322,47,65,112,112,68,97,116,97,47,82,111,97,109,105,110,103,47,82,97,98,98,105,116,77,81,47,108,111,103,47,114,97,98,98,105,116,64,73,53,45,51,53,55,48,75,46,108,111,103],
    [67,58,47,85,115,101,114,115,47,80,105,111,116,114,32,82,97,99,104,119,97,322,47,65,112,112,68,97,116,97,47,82,111,97,109,105,110,103,47,82,97,98,98,105,116,77,81,47,108,111,103,47,114,97,98,98,105,116,64,73,53,45,51,53,55,48,75,45,115,97,115,108,46,108,111,103]]],
    []},
    {rabbit,basic_boot_error,3,[]},
    {rabbit,start_it,1,[]},
    {init,start_it,1,[{file,"init.erl"},{line,1057}]},
    {init,start_em,1,[{file,"init.erl"},{line,1037}]}]
    }}
    init terminating in do_boot ()
```

In server log file I found that message:

```
=CRASH REPORT==== 3-May-2014::18:04:35 ===
crasher:
    initial call: application_master:init/4
    pid: <0.70.0>
    registered_name: []
    exception exit: {bad_return,
                        {{rabbit,start,[normal,[]]},
                         {'EXIT',
                             {badarg,
                                 [{io,format,
                                      [<0.70.0>,
                                       "~n              ~s ~s. ~s~n  ##  ##...",
                                       ["RabbitMQ","3.3.1",
                                        "Copyright (C) 2007-2014 GoP...",
                                        "Licensed under the MPL.  S...",
                                        [67,58,47,85,115,101,114,115,47,80,
                                         105,111,116,114,32,82,97,99,104,119,
                                         97,322,47,65,112,112,68,97,'...'],
                                        [67,58,47,85,115,101,114,115,47,80,
                                         105,111,116,114,32,82,97,99,104,119,
                                         97,322,47,65,112,112,68,'...']]],
                                      []},
                                  {rabbit,start,2,[]},
                                  {application_master,start_it_old,4,
                                      [{file,"application_master.erl"},
                                       {line,272}]}]}}}}
      in function  application_master:init/4 (application_master.erl, line 133)
    ancestors: [<0.69.0>]
    messages: [{'EXIT',<0.71.0>,normal}]
    links: [<0.69.0>,<0.7.0>]
    dictionary: []
    trap_exit: true
    status: running
    heap_size: 2586
    stack_size: 27
    reductions: 306
  neighbours:
```

I use default server configuration. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you have non-latin characters or whitespaces in path to directory with RabbitMQ and to directory with it logs? This line `Log files (may contain more information):~n   ~s~n   ~s~n~n"` should contain log files path but it contains garbage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try to start sasl prior to launch the rabbit server (application:start(sasl)) in order to get more information. I have checked the code of the function start(normal,[]) in rabbit module of rabbitmq-server on github, and I didn't see direct call to io:format/2. A more detailed report could help.

What you can see is that the io:format failed, with badarg reason, the format and parameters are truncated in the display, so it is not possible to be sure of the error, but a possible reason is that the length of the parameter list does not fit to the format definition.

Answer (score 0):

you should check the parameters in function `io:format`.

for the log, there is `{badarg,
                                 [{io,format,`. this is the error reason.